# Find the most frequent element in a masked array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, data-structures

I need to find the most frequent element in a numpy array "label", only if those elements lie inside the mask array. Here is the brute force approach:

```
def getlabel(mask, label):
    # get majority label
    assert label.shape == mask.shape

    tmp = []
    for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mask.shape[1]):
            if mask[i][j] == True:
                tmp.append(label[i][j])
    return Counter(tmp).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

However I don't think this is the most elegant and fastest approach yet. Which other data structures should I use? (hasing, dictionary, etc... )?

Comment: what are in your arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `mask` is a boolean array:

```
import numpy as np

cnt = np.bincount(label[mask].flat)
```

This gives you a vector of number of occurrences of values 0, 1, 2, ... max(label)

You can find the most frequent then by

```
most_frequent = np.argmax(cnt)
```

And naturally, the number of these elements in your input data is

```
cnt[most_frequent]
```

Usually, `np.bincount` is fast. Let us try with labels with maximum number of 999 (i.e. 1000 bins) and a 10 000 000 element array masked by 8 000 000 values:

```
data = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (1000, 10000))
mask = np.random.random((1000, 10000)) < 0.8

# time this section
cnt = np.bincount(data[mask].flat)
```

With my machine this takes 80 ms. The `argmax` takes maybe 2 ns/bin, so even if your label integers are a bit scattered, it does not really matter.

This approach is probably the fastest approach if the following conditions hold:

- the labels are integers within range 0..N, where N is not much more than the size of the input array
- the input data is in a NumPy array

This solution may be applied to some other cases, but then it is more a question of how and whether there are better solutions available. (See `metaperture`'s answer.) For example, a simple conversion of a Python list into `ndarray` is rather costly, and the speed benefit gained by `bincount` will be lost if the input is a Python list, and the amount of data is not large.

The sparsity of labels in the integer space is not a problem *per se*. Creating and zeroing the output vector is relatively fast, and it is easy and fast to compress back with `np.nonzero`. However, if the maximum label value is large compared to the size of the input array, then the speed benefit may be lost.

Answer (score 1):

`np.bincount` is **not** a general approach.`np.bincount` will be faster for bounded, low entropy, discrete distributions. However, it will fail:

- if the distribution is unbounded, the memory used is unbounded (can be arbitrarily large for an arbitrarily small input array)
- if the distribution is continuous, the argmax of bincount is not the mode (technically it's the MAP of a KDE, where the KDE is generated using histogram-like methods)
- if the distribution has high entropy/dispersal, then the bin-based representation of np.bincount doesn't make sense (won't fail but will just be worse)

For a general solution, you should do one of:

```
cnt = Counter((l for m, l in zip(mask.flat, label.flat) if m)) # or...
cnt = Counter(label[mask].flat)
```

Or:

```
scipy.stats.mode(label[mask].flat)
```

In my testing the former is ~20x faster. If you know the distribution is discrete with a relatively low bound and entropy then bincount will be faster.

If the above is not fast enough, a better general approach than bincount is to sample your data

```
collections.Counter(np.random.choice(data[mask], 1000)).most_common(1)
scipy.stats.mode(np.random.choice(data[mask], 1000))
```

Both of the above are an order of magnitude faster than the unsampled versions and converge to the mode quickly for even the most pathological distributions.

Comment: These are nice Python solutions without too much NumPy. However, the performance is not that good; the first one takes 6.95 s (= 85x) and the second one takes 3.59 s (= 45x). Of course, sometimes you have insane labels with negative values or values up to billions, and then you have to do something. (I would create a conversion array, but there are several options.)

Comment: For the narrow use case in your test, I'd agree that `bincount` is more efficient. However, for the reasons above, it's not a good general solution to this question.